# Alternatives for 'Handles Me.FormClosing' in modules

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know of any alternatives to the 'Handles Me.FormClosing' in modules.

I have created code that will display a confirmation message upon clicking the 'X' button. The issue is, I need to put this code into a module to use on multiple forms where i can call it, however, when I attempt to do this the 'Handles Me.FormClosing' will not work.

Here is the code i am using:

```
Private Sub Close(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit the application?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        FrmLogin.Close()
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement)

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you create a new form:

```
Dim newForm as Form = New YourFormClass()
AddHandler newForm.FormClosing, AddressOf YourModule.Close
```

This will route all closing events you want through that sub. Then just remove the `Handles Me.Closing` unless there is something you aren't showing us that makes it relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to coding. Where should i input this?

Comment: Wherever you're creating a form that you want to add this to

Answer (score 0):

One possibility ist to create a function in your module which shows the MessageBox and exits Application if "Yes" is clicked else returns `False`.

```
Module YourModule

    Private dontAskAgain As Boolean
    Public Function AskFormClosing() As Boolean
        If dontAskAgain = False Then
            Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit the application?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

            If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
                dontAskAgain = True
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        End If

        Return dontAskAgain
    End Function

End Module
```

And then you only need to set `e.Cancel` to the inverted result of the function.

```
Private Sub Close(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = Not YourModule.AskFormClosing
End Sub
```

---

If you prefer to use AddHandler as suggested by other people, you could use the following method that will lead to the same result.

```
Module YourModule

    Public Sub AskFormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
        If dontAskAgain = False Then
           Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit the application?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

            If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
               dontAskAgain = True
               Application.Exit()
            Else
               e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

And then add the Handler like this:

```
Dim newForm as Form = New YourFormClass()
AddHandler newForm.FormClosing, AddressOf YourModule.AskFormClosing
```

But for your main-Form you will need to add the Handler in the Loading Event, like this:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler Me.FormClosing, AddressOf YourModule.AskFormClosing
End Sub
```

Comment: this code does makes it so the message box pops up, which is great, however, when yes is clicked the program doesn't close, only the current form

Comment: You wrote: _"I need to put this code into a module to use on multiple forms"_, not to close the whole application from all other forms. To make it simple, just put `End` before `Return True` and it will do what you want it to. But this is more a "brutal" way.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about not wording the question correctly. You were heaps of help

Comment: Using `End` to terminate your app is like stopping your car by driving it into a brick wall.  Not the way to go.  Try something like `Application.Exit` instead or make sure you close the main form.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I know, because of this i already wrote that it's a "brutal" method. I've edited my answer and enhanced the code, so that it works properly with `Application.Exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. I made changes to work as you want :

```
Module YourModule

    Public Function AskFormClosing() As Boolean
        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Exit the application?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

And then

```
Private Sub Close(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If YourModule.AskFormClosing Then
        Application.Exit
    Else
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This way it won't cancel the closing if you press "No" on the MessageBox.

Comment: This will make the MessageBox pop up twice. And btw it should be `e.Cancel = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than placing this code in a *module* for reuse, consider create a base `Form` that has the behaviour you wish to share and then have you other forms *inherit* from this base `Form` (rather than from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`).

See [How to: Inherit Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-inherit-windows-forms) on the Microsoft website.